# jqGrid & MVC3 - Adding Model Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, jqgrid

Is it possible to add Model validation to an edit or add jqgrid form? If so, how would it be done? I know that I can create custom validation for each field on a jqGrid form, but how could integrate the default MVC3 validation to jqGrid?

I've been doing it by creating a custom button that loads a partial view on a jQuery dialog. However, I'd like not to make another call to the controller, considering that I can get all my row values directly (even though I'd lose the partial view model validations) through jqGrid get Methods.

Any hints?

Comment: I found this question useful and interesting. Does exist an answer or similar questions? THX!

Comment: @Larry, Nope. Until now i haven't seen any answer or similar questions. However, it's pretty plain to use a partial view and load it on a jquery dialog. If you really want to use the default dialog, you can check the comercial jqGrid. It has almost full integration with asp.net mvc3.

Comment: THX Adriano! I am already using jqgrid on jquery dialogs. Now I need to add/edit records and I have several validations, including custom remote validations on some fields. Do you have other suggestions/hints, please? Thank you!

Comment: @Larry, Well i'm using the add button to load a jquery dialog with all my fields and validation. But that's because i have validation that can only be done on server side and it will be to expensive to put it on the default jqGrid dialog. However, if you have only client side validation, i'd suggest that you use the jqGrid validation. If you need an example, i can email it for you.

Comment: THX Adriano. Unfortunately I have server side validation too, so I prefer to mantain my create/edits views outside jqgrid, until there's no answer to your interesting question.
Please, could you mail me the piece of code to override default add action of jqgrid and open the create/edit dialogs? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not familiar with jqGrid, I've typically done the same thing as you regarding populating jQuery dialogs from a controller action that renders a partial view.

Instead of doing a callback, you could load the partial view when the jqGrid view is rendered. Then just populate the fields from the selected row. Here's some sample code to consider, untested though.

Your Grid View:

```
@model List<Customer>

<!-- create jqGrid here -->

@Html.PartialView("CustomerForm",new Customer());
```

CustomerForm:

```
@model Customer

<div id="CustomerForm">
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save","Customer",...) )
{
   @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CustomerId)
   <div class="control-group">
      @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CustomerName)
      <div class="controls">
          @Html.EditorFor(m => m.CustomerName)
          @Html.ValidationFor(m => m.CustomerName)
      </div>
  </div>
  <p><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Save" /></p>
}
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   var $cf = $('#CustomerForm');
   $cf.dialog({ autoOpen: false }); // see jquery ui docs for exact options


   $('#myGrid .edit, #myGrid .add').click(function() {
       $(this).closest('tr').find('input, select').each(function() {
           $('input[name='+this.name+'], select[name='+this.name+']',$cf).val($(this).val());
       });
       $cf.dialog('open');
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#jqg").jqGrid({
      url: '@Url.Action("GetData")',
        datatype: "json",
        colNames: ['User name', 'Email'],
        colModel: [
        { name: 'UserName', index: 'UserName', width: 150, sortable: true, editable: true },
        { name: 'Email', index: 'Email', width: 150, sortable: true, editable: true, editrules:{email:true, required:false}}
        ],
        caption: "User List"
    });
```

Validation is here `editrules:{email:true, required:false}` (so, if this field is empty it's Ok, but if it contains invalid email check fails).

More informationa and examples in [jqGrid Wiki](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editrules)

And if you want do this check without modify your JS code you can use controls from [Trirand](http://www.trirand.net/aspnetmvc/grid/editclientsidevalidation), which allow you do it on server-side